# ** not working in web.xml security-contraints

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, security-constraint

I want to have unrestricted access for /gadgets/{any directory}/css/*.
I tried to mention like this

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>UnProtected Area</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/gadgets/**/css/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/gadgets/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
     <role-name>LOGIN</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are trying to use is not supported by the servlet specification (downloadable [here](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/index.html)):

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and
>     ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string
>     beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The
>     empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>     application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>     http://host:port//. In this case the path info is ’/’ and
>     the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string
>     containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of
>     the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI
>     minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only

Accordingly, if you need to match all CSS files, your *should* be able to specify it as an extension mapping:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Unprotected Area</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same Problem. My *.css and *.js Files are located in `WebRoot/resources/css` and in `WebRoot/resources/script`. To access those files I added the line `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` to my `"*-servlet.xml"`. 
Now I allowed access for all user-roles by adding following code to my `web.xml` as the last security-constraint:
`<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>CSS and JS Files</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>` 
I hope this helps.